# facebook SDK Javascript and PHP together

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I have intergrated the JS version of Facebook SDK. However it seems that I am unsure how to intergrate the PHP version so that it won't upset the JS version.

My question is the following:

1. If I use the PHP SDK from Facebook, do they have a method to check if the JS version is running?
2. Storing data from FB, What information do I store from FB once the user signs in with FB? I understand their email address and name etc, but is there a API key like Twitter that I need to send with every request?
3. JS post to feed? Is this possible?

Sorry about these three questions, but the documentation on this is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my answers to your questions:

1. The Facebook PHP SDK runs on the server and the JavaScript one runs on the client. It's basically **impossible** to check if the JS SDK "is running" from the server, since the PHP will have been already rendered.
2. Every user that meets the criteria can register a Facebook application from the [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) website. And every app has its own [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions) set by you in the application settings, depending on what you want to achieve. The user has to accept them in order to use your website/service/app which uses the Facebook application. You can basically get any information from the user (which Facebook exposes, of course) with the right application permissions set.

The basic setup of the JS SDK on your website requires adding this code once in your HTML (PHP) file:

```html
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'your-app-id',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.6'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Please not that you must replace the **appId** property with your actual application ID.

On the client-side, you can use the **FB.login** function to log the user in with Facebook. You can check out the [usage of this function](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.6) in their documentation. The function receives a callback as its first argument, so you can decide what to do with the user data (the **response** variable) in this callback.

3. Posting to the user's feed is very easy with the JS SDK. It requires the **publish_actions** permission though. You can see an example of posting to the feed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/examples).

I don't know why would you use both the JS and PHP SDKs. I suggest using the JS SDK and sending AJAX requests with client-side data to the server, so that you are able to store information.

Comment: Thank you, I know if I kept reading the docs I mosty likely would of worked it out, but I get confused reading large document.